# RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES) vs RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)

Tags: angular, router

What is the differences between these two and what are the use cases for each?

The [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html) aren't exactly helpful:

> forRoot creates a module that contains all the directives, the given
> routes, and the router service itself.
>
> forChild creates a module that
> contains all the directives and the given routes, but does not include
> the router service.

My vague guess is that one is for the 'main' module and the other is for any imported modules (since they would already have the service available from the main module), but I can't really think of a use case.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you don't understand? The quote you've included literally tells you what the difference is.

Comment: I don't understand what the point of using .forChild() is. When would I want the directives and the routes without the service? In the meantime, please answer the question you deleted from the post...

Comment: There should only be one `RouterService` for a single Angular2 application. `forRoot` will initialize that service and register it to DI together with some route config, while `forChild` will only register additional route configs and tell Angular2 to reuse the `RouterService` that `forRoot` has created.

Comment: @HarryNinh: Thanks - that's what I was looking for. When would you want to register additional routes outside of the initial registration though? Seems kind of silly. I am guessing there is no way to create routes dynamically.

Comment: @VSO follow the Angular 2 tutorial on modules and you'll see exactly why: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html. *"please answer the question you deleted from the post"* - no, for the same reason I removed it.

Comment: The doc is quite clear on the purpose of `forChild`, it is for *submodules and lazy loaded submodules*.

Comment: see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLns6s02O48) by angular router author victor.

Comment: There is a video for that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puscOjMyouc

Answer (score 172, accepted):

I strongly suggest reading this article:

- [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://indepth.dev/posts/1056/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular)

#### Module with providers

When you import a module you usually use a reference to the module class:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [AService]
})
export class A {}

-----------------------------------

@NgModule({
    imports: [A]
})
export class B
```

In this way all providers registered on module `A` will be added to the root injector and available for the entire application.

But there is another way to register a module with providers like this:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [AService]
})
class A {}

export const moduleWithProviders = {
    ngModule: A,
    providers: [AService]
};

----------------------

@NgModule({
    imports: [moduleWithProviders]
})
export class B
```

This has the same implications as the previous one.

You probably know that lazy loaded modules have their own injector. So suppose you want to register `AService` to be available for the entire application, but some `BService` to be available to only lazy loaded modules. You can refactor your module like this:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [AService]
})
class A {}

export const moduleWithProvidersForRoot = {
    ngModule: A,
    providers: [AService]
};

export const moduleWithProvidersForChild = {
    ngModule: A,
    providers: [BService]
};

------------------------------------------

@NgModule({
    imports: [moduleWithProvidersForRoot]
})
export class B
    
// lazy loaded module    
@NgModule({
    imports: [moduleWithProvidersForChild]
})
export class C
```

Now `BService` will only be available for child lazy loaded modules and `AService` will be available for the entire application.

You can rewrite the above as an exported module like this:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [AService]
})
class A {
    forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: A,
            providers: [AService]
        }
    }

    forChild() {
        return {
            ngModule: A,
            providers: [BService]
        }
    }
}

--------------------------------------

@NgModule({
    imports: [A.forRoot()]
})
export class B

// lazy loaded module
@NgModule({
    imports: [A.forChild()]
})
export class C
```

###How is that relevant to RouterModule?
Suppose they are both accessed using the same token:

```
export const moduleWithProvidersForRoot = {
    ngModule: A,
    providers: [{provide: token, useClass: AService}]
};

export const moduleWithProvidersForChild = {
    ngModule: A,
    providers: [{provide: token, useClass: BService}]
};
```

With separate configurations when you request `token` from a lazy loaded module you will get `BService` just as planned.

RouterModule uses `ROUTES` token to get all routes specific to a module. Since it wants routes specific to lazy loaded module to be available inside this module (analogues to our BService) it uses different configuration for the lazy loaded child modules:

```
static forChild(routes: Routes): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: RouterModule, 
        providers: [{provide: ROUTES, multi: true, useValue: routes}]
    };
}
```

Comment: so in other words, we should call forChild() in feature modules because forRoot() was already called in the root module and all necessary services were added. So calling forRoot() again will lead to unpredictable states?

Comment: @Wachburn, calling `forRoot` in a lazy loaded module will create new instances of all global services in the lazy loaded module injector. Yes, this will lead to unpredictable results. Also read this article [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: Shouldn't this contain a disclaimer that the author of the linked article is the same as the author of this answer?

Comment: @Willwsharp, why?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I believe that is a rule stipulated by StackOverflow.  As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

the last sentence in the first paragraph: "However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."

I don't plan on flagging this question just wanted to give you a heads up.

Comment: Can you highlight what's different in terms of configuration? It's not obvious.

Comment: @Andy, what do you mean by `in terms of congifuration`? These methods just defines different sets of providers

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I'm referring to whatever you meant by "configurations" in your answer.

Comment: Hi. I think you've missed one service in providers : https://i.imgur.com/iQuGIKJ.jpg

Comment: And also static for both functions

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I was just showing how you can split the services using static methods and ModuleWithProviders structure

Comment: I completely understand this. But What is the difference between Routermodule.foRoot, VS Routermodule.forChild? forRoot &forChild are just static method which gives object in return based on the value passed. So in app module , why i am not able to use forChild?? why its throwing error?
Why i cant use multiple forRoot?

Comment: At times, it is just good to go straight to the point with answers.
information overload most times leads to more confusion.

Comment: Very well formatted answer, I appreciate that! I think Angular in it's tutorial should insist more on the project configuration and the core structure of an Angular application, to optimize from the start, and have the sufficient knowledge to avoid bloating your app.

Answer (score 44):

I think the answers are right but I think something is missing.
The thing which is missing is "why and what it solves ?".
Ok let's start.

First let's mention some info:

All modules has access to the root services.
So even lazy loaded modules can use a service which was provided in `app.module`.
What will happen if a lazy loaded module will provide to itself  a service which the app module already provided ? there will be **2** instances.
It's not a problem *but sometimes it is*.
How can we solve it ? simply don't import a module with that provider to lazy loaded modules.

**End of story.**

This ^ was just to show that lazy loaded modules has their own injection point ( as opposed to non-lazy-loaded modules).

But what happens when a *shared(!)* module has declared `providers`, and that module is imported by lazy **and** `app.module`? Again, like we said, two instances.

So how can we solve this in the shared module POV ? We need a way **not** to use `providers:[]` ! Why?  because they will be auto imported  to both consuming lazy and app.module and we don't want that as we saw that each will have a different instance.

Well, it turns out that we can declare a shared module that won't have `providers:[]`, but still, will provide providers ( sorry :))

How? Like this :

[image]

Notice, no providers.

But

- what will happen now when app.module will import the shared module with POV of service ? NOTHING.
- what will happen now when a lazy module will import the shared module with POV of service ? NOTHING.

**Entering Manual mechanism via convention :**

You will notice that the providers in the pictures have `service1` and `service2`

This allows us to import `service2` for lazy loaded modules and `service1` for non-lazy modules. ( *cough...router....cough*)

BTW, no one is stopping  you to call `forRoot` within a lazy module. but you will have 2 instances because `app.module` should also do it - so **don't** do it in lazy modules.

Also - if `app.module` calls `forRoot` (and no one calls `forchild`) - that's fine, but root injector will only have `service1`. ( available to all app)

So why do we need it? I'd say  :

> It allows a shared module , to be able to **split** its
> different-providers to be used with eager modules and lazy modules -
> via `forRoot` and `forChild` convention. I repeat : **convention**

**That's it.**

> **WAIT !!** not a single word about singleton ?? so why do I read
> singleton everywhere ?

Well - it's hidden  in the sentence above ^

> It allows a shared module, to be able to **split** its
> different-providers to be used with eager modules and lazy modules -
> via **forRoot and forChild**.

The **convention** (!!!) allows it to be singleton - or to be more precise - if you won't follow the convention - you will **NOT** get a singleton.
So if you only load `forRoot` in the `app.module`  , then you get only one instance because you only should call `forRoot` it in the `app.module`.
BTW  - at this point you can forget about `forChild`. the lazy loaded module shouldn't / won't call `forRoot` - so you're safe in POV of singleton.

forRoot and forChild are not one unbreakable  package - it's just that there is no point of calling for Root which obviously will be loaded only in `app.module`   without giving the ability for lazy modules , have their own services , without creating new services-which-should-be-singleton.

This convention give you a nice ability called `forChild` - to consume "services only for lazy loaded modules".

[**Here is a demo Root providers yields positive numbers , lazy loaded modules yields negative numbers.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/forroot-forchild-example-c7vzse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile%2Fprofile.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodule2%2Fservice2.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodule2%2Fservice1.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmodule2%2Fmodule2.module.ts)

Comment: 1. What is POV here? 2. The stackblitz doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @NicholasK this stackblitz is always messes up things after a while. i will try to upload new version

Comment: @RoyiNamir As you have mentioned the lazy-loaded modules also access root modules providers, then why we need to add them again in lazy modules? Even in the case of the shared module also, if we have added in the root module then why I would add a shared module again in the lazy loaded module? Any providers that are not there in the root but needed in the lazy module, I can add them separately in the lazy modules. right? So why it's required. still confused about their usage.

Comment: @NicholasK POV = PointOfView (https://i.imgur.com/EDtF1qA.jpg)

Answer (score 30):

Documentation clearly states what is the purpose of this distinction here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root

> Call forRoot only in the root application module, AppModule. Calling it in any other module, particularly in a lazy loaded module, is contrary to the intent and is likely to produce a runtime error.
>
> Remember to import the result; don't add it to any other @NgModule list.

Every application has exactly one starting point (root) where the main routing service should be initialized with `forRoot`, while routes for particular "child" features should be registered additionaly with `forChild`. It is extremely useful for submodules and lazy loaded modules which do not have to be loaded at the application start, and as @Harry Ninh said they are told to reuse RouterService instead of registration of the new service, which may cause a runtime error.

Comment: Those documents seem to be moved, https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root

Answer (score 6):

**The `forRoot` Static Method:**

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

The forRoot static method is the method that configures the root routing module for your app. When you call RouterModule.forRoot(routes), you are asking Angular to instantiate an instance of the Router class globally. Just like Angular creates a new base AppModule to import all of your feature modules, it also provides the AppRoutingModule to import all of your child routes.

In the new app that you have created via the Angular CLI, the forRoot method is actually already being used inside of the app-routing.module.ts. In your app, you only want to use the forRoot method once. This is because this method tells Angular to instantiate an instance of the Router class under the hood, and there can be only one router in your app. The forRoot static method is a part of a pattern that ensures that you are using singleton classes.

**Child Routes:**

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

When you are using the forChild static method, you are basically telling Angular, "There is already a Router instance available in the app so please just register all of these routes with that instance." The forChild method is the method that you will call to register routes throughout your app and you will use it inside of the child, routing modules that you create.

The forChild static method is useful because it plays a core part of Angular module functionality by allowing you to maintain separation of concerns within your app.

Suppose you want to create a new feature module for user settings in your app and this feature will contain a few routes. Instead of adding these routes into the AppRoutingModule directly, which would eventually become untenable as your app grows, you can maintain separation of concerns within your app by using the forChild method. First, create a new UserSettingsRoutingModule.

```
import { NgModule } from  '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from  '@angular/router';

import { UserSettingsComponent } from './user-settings.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from  './user-profile/user-profile.component';

const  routes:  Routes  = [
    {
        path:  'settings',
        component:  UserSettingsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path:  'profile',
                component: UserProfileComponent 
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export  class  UserSettingsRoutingModule { }
```

Note the use of the forChild method above. Since you have already used the forRoot method, you'll just want to register your routes to the already instantiated app router.

Now you need to create your UserSettingsModule like this:

```
import { NgModule, CommonModule } from  '@angular/core';
import { UserSettingsRoutingModule } from  './user-settings-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        UserSettingsRoutingModule
    ],
    // Configure the rest of your module here
})
export class UserSettingsModule { }
```

And there you have it! Now all you would need to do is import this UserSettingsModule into your root, AppModule, and your child routes that point to their respective components would be configured within your app.

I hope that this guide has helped you to understand how the Angular Router static methods forRoot and forChild can help you to create well-structured routes within your app. For more information, check out [documentation](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/forroot-and-forchild-static-methods-on-the-angular-router)

Answer (score 2):

If appRoutes contains path to various functions in the site (admin crud, user crud, book crud) and we want to separate them we could simply do that :

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(categoriesRoutes),
    RouterModule.forRoot(auteursRoutes),
  ],
```

And for routes :

```
const auteursRoutes:Routes=[
  {path:'auteurs/ajouter',component:CreerAuteurComponent},
]
const categoriesRoutes: Routes = [


  {path:'categories/consulter',component:ConsultercategoriesComponent},
  {path:'categories/getsouscategoriesbyid/:id',component:GetsouscategoriesbyIDComponent},
  {path:'categories/ajout',component:CreerCategorieComponent},
 {path:'categories/:id',component:ModifiercategorieComponent},
 {path:'souscategories/ajout/:id',component:AjoutersouscategorieComponent},
 {path:'souscategories/lecture/:id1',component:SouscategoriesComponent},
 {path:'souscategories/modifier/:id1',component:ModifiersupprimersouscategorieComponent},
  {path:'uploadfile',component:UploadfileComponent},
  {path:'categories',component:ConsultercategoriesComponent},



]
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `forRoot` twice

Answer (score 2):

Consider this as the implementation of router module for the sake of understanding.
Lazyloaded routes and common routes has to be handle seperately,supporting lazy loading

```
   @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        
      ],
      exports: [],
    })
    export class RouteModule {
      static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<RouteModule> {
        return { ngModule: RouteModule, providers: [routerHistoryService,handleCommonRoutesService] };
      }
    
      static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders<RouteModule> {
        return {
          ngModule: RouteModule, providers: [handleChildRouterService]
        };
      }
    }
```

forroot ->
will add routerModule with providers (services) , so all the services need for
common angular routing
(example routerHistoryService ) will be  injected to root injector from the app module(root  module)

forchild ->
will add routerModule with providers(services) ,but as common services(ex
routerHistoryService ) already added in to root
injector ,from the lazy loaded modules,we may able to use them and no need to add again,if we
add it will create two instances.
but there could be services, specifically needed for handle
child routes. so in that case when call the  forchild we can ,provide them (exmple
:handleChildRouterService)

if the routerModule if we do not implement forRoot and forChild Consider the below scenario

1)in the root injectors routerHistoryService previous route is
"home/lazymodule"

2)but in lazy module with new history service ,previous route is null

so it does not have data to go back when back button clicks.
Thats why routerModule has implemeted following this pattern to ensure router module got only single instance
throughout the application