# RouterModule: Router Instance

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wish to have access to RouterModule directive(routerLink) in my child Module, tough I don't have any Routes to add to the forChild method.
Which way should I import RouterModule in my @NgModule class without getting another instance of Router(That was already instantiated in the root application module through RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)):

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild([])]
})
```

OR

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Both seem to work in my app. I'm just not sure if the service instance is happening twice.

I've read these two entries of the documentation:

> The result is that the root application module imports RouterModule.forRoot(...) and gets a Router, whereas all route components import RouterModule which does not include the Router.[[1]](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

And:

> For submodules and lazy loaded submodules the module should be used as follows[[2]](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule):

```
  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)]
  })
  class MyNgModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have **routerLink** directive without importing **RouterModule**. You have to simply import it into your child module without calling **RouterModule.forChild()** method.

For the better understanding of **forRoot()** and **forChild()**, please refer below links:

[RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES) vs RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498081/routermodule-forrootroutes-vs-routermodule-forchildroutes)

[Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)