# Angular 6 Lazy Loading throws error

Tags: angular

I have created routes in `app.routes.ts` file and imported in `app.module.ts` file. Strangely I'm getting an error saying that `RouterModule.forRoot()` was called twice

[Error In Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARKRU.png)

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Solved: Inner Modules I have used Routermodule.forRoot() changed to Routermodule.forChild(). working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The error says it all*.

There should be only one `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` in your application, which should be on the root `module` of your application (Usually `AppModule`). All the other child modules (particularly lazy loading modules) should import `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`.

See the diff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498081/routermodule-forrootroutes-vs-routermodule-forchildroutes)

Comment: Perfect solution and I did same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `forChild` for lazy module routing and exports `RouterModule`

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-loading-is-not-working-for-angular-4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustomers%2Fcustomers.module.ts)**

```
imports:[
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
],
exports:[
    RouterModule
]
```

Comment: Thanks Man for your time