# The default component is not shown Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I need your help. I'm trying to write a small authorization, and I started by setting a default component to be shown first. To do this, I created a separate `AppRoutingModule` and installed the components in it, and then inserted it into the main `AppMoudle`. I have no errors, but none of the components show up. What is my mistake. Thank you very much

AppRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from "./components/login/login.component";
import {MainContentComponent} from "./components/main-content/main-content.component";
import {AuthGuard} from "./guards/auth.guard";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'content', component: MainContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

AppModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { MainContentComponent } from './components/main-content/main-content.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    MainContentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppComponentHtml

```
<div class="all_content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` instead of `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` when the routing module is imported into the root module of your app.

Comment: @MikeS. Thank you, you helped me)) One question, what the difference between for root and for child?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498081/routermodule-forrootroutes-vs-routermodule-forchildroutes) question sums it up quite nicely :)